# JQuery include in phantomjs is not working

Tags: phantomjs

My code is:

```js
var url = 'https://search.yahoo.com/',
page = new WebPage(),

fs = require('fs');

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (platform; rv:geckoversion) Gecko/geckotrail appname/appversion';

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};

page.open(url, function(status) {

    if (status !== 'success')
    {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
        phantom.exit();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        page.includeJs("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js", function()
        {
            page.evaluate(function()
            {
                $('#yschsp').val("ask question");
                $(".sbb").click();
            });   

            page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
                var content = page.content;
                fs.write('1.html', content, 'w');
                console.log($('#link-1').val());
                phantom.exit();
            };
        });
    }
});
```

JQuery works perfect in `page.evaluate` but does not work in `page.onLoadFinished`. I get an error

> Can't get variable: $

That means that in function `page.onLoadFinished` jquery is not working. But I can not understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jQuery is loaded into the page context, you can only use there. The only function that interfaces with the page context is [`evaluate`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) (and the other `evaluate` functions).

So this line

```
console.log($('#link-1').val());
```

must be inside of an `evaluate` callback. Since you have a `page.onConsoleMessage` event handler you will receive the console message from the page context.

The other thing is that adding an `page.onLoadFinished` event handler after the page has loaded isn't doing anything useful. You can remove the handler surrounding your code since the page load is finished when the `page.open` callback is called.

---

If `#link-1` is not yet loaded, you should either log the value after a static timeout (`setTimeout`) or use [`waitFor`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js).